# Dictionary in list in dictionnary with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

For a project, I have a dictionary in a list itself in a dictionary.
But I don't know how print the last dictionary...

> ```
> dic = {
>    "Serial" : "test"
>    "servers":
>    [
>        "url" : "http://foo.com"
>        "service" :   #it's this I want to print
>        {
>            "url" : "http://service1.com"
>            "expected_code" : 200
>        }
>    ]
> }
> ```

Somebody know how to do ?

Comment: Doing some guesswork with your missing braces, I don't see why you can't just print it with normal accessing `print dic['servers'][0]['service']`

Comment: Your dic is not a valid dic.

Comment: Your code is not valid at all so no chance to print anything but errors

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I don't know I can do like that, indeed it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is not valid.

Try something like that :

```
dic = {"Serial" : "test", "servers" : [{"url" : "http://foo.com", "service" : {"url" : "http://service1.com", "expected_code" : 200}}]}
```

And then you will be able to print your last dict :

```
dic['servers'][0]['service']
```

Answer (score 0):

change your dictionary to

```
dic = {"Serial" : "test","servers":[{"url" : "http://foo.com","service" :{"url" : "http://service1.com","expected_code" : 200}}]}
```

then `dic['servers'][0]['service']`  will give you desired output

Comment: The dictionary in this post is valid.

Comment: @Jokab No, it is not. What does `"url" : "http://foo.com"` inside a list mean? Why are there no commas to separate elements?

Comment: @Mitch My comment was in response to a comment on this answer. I am seeing the commas in Dark Matter's answer, aren't you? I ran the exact command listed here in the Python interpreter and it worked fine. I don't know what the url key is supposed to mean, but does not make the dictionary itself invalid. It is possible that it is poorly constructed, yes, but not invalid.

Comment: @Jokab Ah, the comment was deleted, I thought you were referring to the original OP's question's dict.